# Как сохранить состояние Checkbox'a?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

В моем приложении используются `CheckBox`'ы. В разметке моей активности указан объект `CheckBox`, который должен сохранять свое состояние после закрытия активности тоже, но как это реализовать? Как сохранить состояние `CheckBox`'a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сохранить в [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) например

```
public static String PREF_IS_CHECKED = "is_checked";
```

---

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     CheckBox checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

     boolean isChecked = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(PREF_IS_CHECKED, false);
     checkBox.setChecked(isChecked);

 }
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putBoolean(PREF_IS_CHECKED, checkBox.isChecked())
            .apply();
}
```